# Cache atime writes

Tags: linux, filesystems, performance, ext4, atime

Is there a way to set atime writes to be cached for a very long time? I *need* atime (that is to say, relatime won't cut it), but I don't want it to effect performance so much. Data loss in of atimes (and atimes only) is acceptable in some cases (e.g. power failure).

Comment: I think I read about this, or something similar, a couple months ago. So probably yes. Sorry can not remember anything more. Was reading about new kernel features regarding SSDs.

Comment: @richard: `lazytime`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found `lazytime`, a mount option for ext4, that solves this satisfactorily for me.

https://lwn.net/Articles/620086/

> This mode causes atime, mtime, and ctime updates to only be made to the in-memory version of the inode.  The on-disk times will only get updated when (a) when the inode table block for the inode needs to be updated for some non-time related change involving any inode in the block, (b) if userspace calls fsync(), or (c) the refcount on an undeleted inode goes to zero (in most cases, when the last file descriptor assoicated with the inode is closed).

This option is available since kernel 4.0.

As well, it is necessary to override the default of `relatime`, otherwise you get `relatime` functionality in addition to the caching functionality of `lazytime`. To do this, mount with `strictatime` AND `lazytime`.

Comment: "Data loss in of atimes (and atimes only) is acceptable in some cases (e.g. power failure)." It would be nice if this answer explicitly acknowledged that you decided it was acceptable to lose mtimes/ctimes on power loss. If you have some reasoning then it might help other readers make such a decision.

Comment: Yes. Note this is not just ext4: XFS has this, and [ZFS is working on it](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/9843) I think unwritten data of any kind is lost with power cord pulling, unless heroic/enterprise care is taken (e.g. battery-backed RAM write caches): atimes just have a different shelf-life in the write cache. I also think this probably applies as a matter of principal to any filesystem. The problem is now a mismatch of file contents and metadata, which could be repaired to relatime-equivalent after restoring power.